# GCP Firestore document db creation using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, terraform, jsonencoder

I am using terraform resource google_firestore_document to create firestor document db and i was abel to create it successfully.
I am trying to convert it to a module for which I need to build the values in jsonencode format.
example:

```
 ` + fields      = jsonencode(
        {
          + akey      = {
              + stringValue = "avalue"
            }
          + createdBy = {
              + stringValue = "xyz"
            }
        }
    )`
```

I have created a variable as below.

```
`variable "fields" {
    description = "field details"
    default = {"fname":{"stringValue":"xyz"}}
}`
```

and main.tf is:

```
   ` resource "google_firestore_document" "default" {
    project     = "var.project"
    collection  = "var.collection"
    document_id = "var.document_id"
    fields = jsonencode({ fields = var.fields})
  }`
```

output is and it is not correct.

```
  ` + fields      = jsonencode(
        {
          + fields = {
              + fname = {
                  + stringValue = "xyz"
                }
            }
        }
      )`
```

I tried to build with `fields = jsonencode({var.fields})` but it says
Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value
Please let me know how can we achieve it without two fields section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `=` instead of `:` in variable definition. I found example in this [post](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9112#issuecomment-433519582). I think it will be something like:

```
`variable "fields" {
    description = "field details"
    default = {
      "fname" = {
         "stringValue" = "xyz"
      }
    }
}`
```

Although I do not have playground to test it (so please treat it as pseudo code).